# Is it possible to use onboard video card together with a separate video card? I can't get both screen simultaneous

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, projector

I installed EN210 SILENT/DI/1GD3/V2(LP) ASUS video card as a separate video card for connecting my projector screen in CPU.

I had installed onboard Intel card for my monitor screen.

I am using windows 10, so that driver doesn't create problem. It was working since many years, just video card was dead and I changed the new one of same type.I just don't know what feature enable both of the card can work together.

My Bios is UEFI utility one, and there is just three options : Cpu_graphis , Pci-e , auto.

If I used Cpu-graphics ,only onboard video card works.
If I used Pci-e , only ASUS video card work and monitor screen doesn't work.
If I use auto still just one card work at the same time.

Please help me how both screen will work together, at the same time.

Solution I used:

1. Advance display settings : tried to detect another screen but it can just detect 1 screen.
2. device manager can't detect 2 video card at the same time.

Comment: Some mainboards support this, others do not. Unless you can find documentation noting that your mainboard does support this, it may be the case that it is simply not an option.

Comment: It was working from 10 years, video card was dead and I changed the new one. After that I do not know the option how to make it work together.

Comment: BIOS is usually the place to start if it worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is Change the Graphics Configuration settings in Bios to Enable the PCI-E card and Extend the display with CPU-graphics.

Then, Update the recent driver for external video card. Windows 10 have the driver but those doesn't support always.

After these steps it is working fine now.